# it is possible to turn on gps from mobile browser?

Tags: laravel, gps, mobile-browser

I have website based on laravel framework and I use geolocation maps api inside my website. When user access my website from mobile browser and their gps is turn of, can I turn on the gps from mobile browser chrome/firefox ? Like in the android/iOs app..

Comment: The Geolocation API is accessed via a call to navigator.geolocation; this will cause the user's browser to ask them for permission to access their location data. If they accept, then the browser will use the best available functionality on the device to access this information (for example, GPS).

Comment: @VPC Yes, that's right. But, when my phone gps is turn off, the browser won't ask for permission access device location. Until I turn on manually my phone gps from setting. It is possible to show alert with action to turn on gps when user device gps is turn off ?